# SalesForce SOAP API: Find UserId by Name

Tags: java, soap, salesforce

So I am trying to find a User using their ID using the Salesforce API. But I am running into problems on how to do so. Currently I have:

```
    private static HashMap<String, id> getUserIdByName = new HashMap<String, id>();
//private String id = null;
public static String getUserIdByName(final String profileName) throws ConnectionException {
    if (profileName == null && profileName.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Something is wrong with the profile name");
    }
    if (getUserIdByName.containsKey(profileName)) {
        return getUserIdByName.get(profileName);
    } else {
        try {
            id profileId = GET_USER_ID_BY_NAME;
            getUserIdByName.put(profileName, profileId);
            return profileId; //private static final String GET_USER_ID_BY_NAME = "SELECT id From Profile WHERE Name='%s'"; //%s
        } catch (QueryException qex) {
            System.out.print("Error" + qex.getMessage());
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error with the query!");

        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Currently this is what I have and I cannot for the life of me figure out why I "id" cannot be resolved. I think I have the majority of the method written correctly but I could be wrong. Thanks for the help!

Another version I have been working on is:

```
public String getUserIdByName(final String userId) throws ConnectionException {
    String id = null;
    final String sql = String.format(GET_USER_ID_BY_NAME, StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(userId));
    final QueryResult queryResult = partnerConnection.query(sql);
    for(final SObject User : queryResult.getRecords()) {
        id = User.getId();
        System.out.println(User);
    }
    return id;
    }
```

The query I am using for both of them is: SELECT id From Profile WHERE Name='%s'"

I am a bit more confident about the second one but I am still not able to get the correct ID.

Comment: You say you're looking for a userId, but you are querying profile not user, if you really want a user then your query will need to be select id from user where name ='%s'

Comment: Well I am looking for the Id of a User when I give the name of the user as a parameter. So, if I give the name "Joe Smith" it should return and Id such as "11111"

Comment: Then you should query user not profile.